# How to tell if an internal hard drive works in a laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

What are the factors one should take into consideration when choosing internal HDD for laptops?

Are things like height, power, rotational speed, and buffer-host max. rate important?

Comment: What kind of laptop is it? I'd need at least the model number to answer that question.

Comment: @WesSayeed I meant in general. what are the factors one should take into consideration when choosing internal HDD for laptops.

Comment: A veeeery non-explanatory title.:( The question itself is also strange. Obviously, many hard drives will work on many OS-s. Since no specifics were given, the question seems to be opinion-based.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The useful place to start with is *form factor* and connectors.

Quick rule of thumb - look at your old drive. If it has pins, its probably a 44 pin PATA drive

Looks somewhat like this (that's not actually a drive but close enough).

[image]

Check the size, and connector

The 'standard' for newer laptop hard drives and sata SSDs tends to be 2.5 inch 7mm drives (and that's a safe bet). You can fit this into an older 9.5mm drive's slot, especially with a caddy).

*However* there's a few common variations as well as newer standards, especially for SSDs

[image]
[(Image taken from wikipedia sata)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29)

There's also a *non compatible* msata varient on apple laptops.

Newer models also use the NVMe based m.2 drive which has different keying for PCIe and sata based varient (m2's on the right)

[image]

[Image taken from wikipedia's m2 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2)

As for rotational speeds - typically laptop HDDs are 5400 rpm. They use less power and are cooler. Though 7200 rpm laptop drives exist, if you need more speed, go with an SSD. Power use is something that probably wouldn't determine *if* a drive will work. A drive that needs more power may have an adverse effect on battery life, but I've rarely seen complaints about that.

Comment: For a fun read: [2.5" Form Factor Drive Dimensions as accepted by the EIA](ftp://ftp.seagate.com/pub/sff/SFF-8201.PDF)

Comment: Would a laptop with 9.5mm drive accept the newer 7mm drives?

Comment: Yes. It would. However you *may* need a spacer if the drive bay dosen't use a caddy. Its in my answer but I typoed it. I've upgraded older laptops with caddies, and 9.5mm drives with 7mm drives using the same screwholes.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, laptops use 2.5" hard disk drives (HDD) or solid state drives (SSD).  A standard desktop drive is 3.5" and will not fit in a laptop (unless it is a 2.5" SSD).

The most important factor is the connection.  Modern laptops uses SATA connectors, while much older laptops will use IDE.  There are adapters that will convert one to the other, however using those will most likely cause the drive not to fit.  See the image below for the connectors- note those are 3.5" drives, not 2.5" laptop drives:

[image: Connectors]

Height, is standardized so any 2.5" drive will fit.  Power is standardized as well.  Rotational speed is important, however 2.5" hard drives (not SSDs) will be slower than 3.5" drives.

If you list the make and model of the laptop and drive, we can know with 100% certainty.

Comment: This answer might have been valid 10 years ago, but not today. Most importantly height is *not* standardized, 2.5" drives come in 5mm, 7mm, 9mm, 12.5mm and 15mm heights. Not to mention mSATA, NGFF (M.2), NVMe, SATAe.

Comment: the answer is correct.  @qasdfdsaq is just nitpicking on a few exceptions.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. Drives of different heights are the norm, not the exception. The statement "any 2.5" drive will fit" completely false and misleading. The vast majority of sub-13" laptops do not use 2.5" drives at all.

Comment: I disagree @qasdfdsaq. The vast majority of laptop SATA hard drives are 9.5mm in height.  12mm drives are exceedingly rare, and 15mm ones are only found in servers that use SAS and 10K+ spindle speeds. If the laptop has a standard SATA connector, it will accept practically any 2.5" drive you can buy.

Comment: Also, @qasdfdsaq, I was disagreeing with your first comment, not the second.  You are correct that we would need to know the model to know if it even took a standard SATA drive.  The OP didn't say.

Comment: @WesSayeed: The vast majority of SSDs are not 9.5mm in height, and plenty of modern laptops will not fit 9.5mm drives. HP's EliteBook 820 for example requires a <=7mm 2.5" hard drive or SSD. And that's not even a particularly thin laptop.

Comment: just ignore @qasdfdsaq and his silly comments

Comment: Ignore @Keltari and his incorrect and misleading answers more like.

Comment: Some laptops will take only a thin drive but this issue can be addressed by simply measuring the compartment; no sense arguing about it.  A couple of other thoughts:  1) an old laptop running an ancient version of Windows might have a problem with a huge-capacity drive.  2) Any drive isn't necessarily plug-and-play out of the box for any OS, it might need to first be formatted to an appropriate filesystem.

Comment: Suggestion: the pictures show 3.5" drives (no Molex connectors on 2.5" drives).  It might be better to show 2.5" drives.

Comment: Also the lower hard drive is an odd transitional model, from when sata was new.

Comment: Would a laptop with 9.5mm drive accept the newer 7mm drives?

Comment: @Omne Most likely yes, but there would be empty space which might need filling since the drive might move on transit. Even cardboard for the difference would most likely do it, just must be sure not to block possible air holes.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What are the factors one should take into consideration when choosing internal HDD for laptops?
> 2. Are things like height, power, rotational speed, and buffer-host max. rate important?

1. Price, performance, thickness(how many mm, some drives will not fit), noise.
   Determine how much You have money to buy it, select some drives that will fit.
   Must be same thickness as Your internal drive. Must be same size(such as 2.5 inch). Must be same connection type (IDE/SATA/...). Next factors are speed(faster=better), noise(more silent=better). You may also care how much energy it uses when idle and under load. Next read some reviews You can find in Internet. Select best cost/performance thing. Sometimes manufacturer warranty period is also important.
2. Height - yes, it may not fit if You don't take care. Power - not very much, but still the more it uses the less You can work from battery. Rotational speed - probably, affects speed, noise and reliability. Buffer-host max. rate - not very much, real speed is always lower than this max. rate.